# How to merge cells two ways in a table?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to add a table in my Word document:

1. It has to have three columns
2. Column 1 and 3 should be merged
3. On the second column, row 1 should be merged. Leaving row 2 of the same column unmerged.

Like this:
[image]

The problem is I can't select row 1 of column 2, and merge then.
It doesn't let do it, because I already merged column 1 and column 3.

Answer (score 1):

I started with a 2 x 6 table and merged.

```
Sub makeTable()
   With ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 2, 6)
      .Cell(1, 5).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(2, 6)
      .Cell(1, 3).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(1, 4)
      .Cell(1, 1).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(2, 2)
      .Borders.Enable = True
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim Tbl As Table
With ActiveDocument
  Set Tbl = .Tables.Add(.Range.Characters.Last, 1, 3)
  With Tbl
    .Borders.Enable = True
    .Cell(1, 2).Split 2, 1
    .Cell(2, 2).Split 1, 2
  End With
End With
End Sub
```